# $L^p$ norm of the harmonic polynomial restricted to $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\phi(x)=(x_1+ix_2)^k$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to know the asymptotic property of its  $L^p$ ($1\leq p< \infty$) norm when restricted to $\mathbb{S}^2$, i.e., I want to know for which $\sigma_p$, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}{|\phi(x)|^p\ d\sigma_S})^\frac{1}{p}\to k^{\sigma_p}, as \ k\to\infty
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html we have $|\phi(x)| = \sin^k(\varphi)$.  (You use $\phi$, and this letter is also needed for spherical coordinates, so I'll use $\varphi$ for the spherical coordinate.)

So you are computing the $p$th root of $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\varphi = 0}^\pi \sin^{kp+1}(\varphi) \, d\varphi d\theta $, which can be computed using the Gamma function.

Did I understand your question correctly?